# how to solve this problem in logic expressions problem?

Tags: python

```
z = 1 
x1 = 1
y1 = 1
        
while x1!= 0:
    if y1==0:
        z = 0
        x1 -= 1
     
while y1!=0:
    if x1 ==0:
        z = 0
        y1 -= 1

while x! = 0:
    while y!= 0:
        z +=1 
        x = 0
        y = 0
```

I know I can use OR/ AND ... but I want to solve it using while loops  when two values are different the result ; `z = 0` and when the values are the same then `z = 1`. These values

```
(1,0) = 0
(0,1) = 0
(0,0) = 1
```

except I'm facing this problem with `(1,1)` because the program is looping and I don't know how to handles it - can some one please help?
the expected output is `(1,1) = 1`

Comment: A [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should include what `x` and `y` are. I believe you may have forgotten to include them

Comment: no but I explained as they should be either 1 or 0 since logic expression is the question

Comment: Why loops at all? Such logic calculations don't need loops. You just need `z = x * y` or  `z = x & y` -- which corresponds to a logical AND operation.

Comment: still how would you interpret when  'x1 = 0 , y1 = 0'  when the answer must be 1 ?

Comment: You said at the end of your question that `(0,0)=0`. So is that not true? Then it is `z = int(x == y)` or `z = 1 - (x ^ y)`.

Comment: sorry but I wrote when values are diferent then answer is 0 and when are the same then answer is 1

Comment: OK, I saw your update. So then see my latest comment.

Comment: iit give me an 1 for (1,0) where it should give 0 and the program is looping again on (1,1)

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please check your code. See it run on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomq698034395459839)

Comment: `! =` is invalid. It should be `!=`

Comment: @trincot yes but still the output is 0 for (1,1)

Comment: Please read [ask]. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? If I'm understanding correctly, you're just looking for XNOR, which @trincot suggested in [this comment](/q/69803439#comment123387090_69803439). You can [edit] to clarify. Please provide a [mre] including complete code / example input.

Comment: Can you be clear what you want as output for all four possibilities? I understood you wanted `(0,0)=1` `(0,1)=0` `(1,0)=0` `(1,1)=1`, and that is the output you get with the equation `z=1 - (x ^ y)`. If that is what you expect, then don't say the output is not that, because it is. You should check it.

Comment: @tincot
`(x1,y1) are inputs  as 
(1,1) => z = 1
(0,0) => z = 1
(1,0) => z = 0
(0,1) => z = 0`
and what I get in the console 
`(0,0) --> z = 0
(0,1) ---> z = 1 
(1,0) ----> z = 0
(1,1) -----> z = 0` 
I hope it clear .. i could formatt it to look clearer

Comment: That is exactly the same as I wrote. But your console output is clearly based on something different than what I suggested. Did you really run [this repl](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomq698034395459839)? Its output is as you specify. I am moving on...

Comment: @trincot ..  couldn't work but  thanks though

Comment: What do you see when you run the  repl?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238780/discussion-between-user4556432-and-trincot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first loop will hang when both `x1` and `y1` are 1, because the `if` condition will always be false, and so none of the variables change and the `while` condition will always remain true.

The thing is that you shouldn't use loops at all when dealing with just 0 and 1 values.

The following mapping of `(x, y)` to `z`:

```
 (0, 0) => 1
 (0, 1) => 0
 (1, 0) => 0
 (1, 1) => 1
```

...can be achieved in many ways in Python. Here are a few

```
z = int(x == y)
z = x ^ y ^ 1
z = 1 - (x ^ y)
```

We can imagine the desired outcome of an operation to be represented by a four-digit binary number. In the above case the code would be 1001 (reading the 4 outcomes from top to bottom).

Here is a table of assignments to `z` you can use for the different "codes":

| code | formula |
| --- | --- |
| 0000 | `z = 0` |
| 0001 | `z = x & y` |
| 0010 | `z = (x ^ 1) & y` |
| 0011 | `z = y` |
| 0100 | `z = x & (y ^ 1)` |
| 0101 | `z = x` |
| 0110 | `z = x ^ y` |
| 0111 | `z = x | y` |
| 1001 | `z = x ^ y ^ 1` |
| 1010 | `z = x ^ 1` |
| 1011 | `z = (x ^ 1) | y` |
| 1100 | `z = y ^ 1` |
| 1101 | `z = x | (y ^ 1)` |
| 1110 | `z = (x & y) ^ 1` |
| 1111 | `z = 1` |

Comment: I have to create the XOR or XNOR  within my functions so I can't use  this  ^ 
that's why I had to seek the while loops .. based on while loops, if , and the functions that I posted in the chat

Comment: There is no good reason to use loops for this. If you have trouble implementing this with the restrictions you have then ask a new question specifying which functions and operators you have at your disposal.

Comment: Note that `(x ^ 1)` is the same as `not x`.  You cannot create the complete set of raster ops using just AND and OR.  That is well-known.  You need either NOT, NAND or NOR.